# Proof Verification: All subsets of the natural numbers are at most countable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Proof:
Suppose $X\subset\Bbb{N}$ and $X\neq\emptyset$; By the well-ordering principle $X$ has a minimum element. $\forall X'=X\setminus\{x_0\}\subset\Bbb{N}$ such that $x_0\leq m,\forall m\in X$, we know that that $X'$ still has a minimum element $x_1$, by the well-ordering principle. Clearly, $x_1$ is the next least element in $X$. By defining a function $f:\Bbb{N}\rightarrow X$ such that if $x_n$ is the least element of $X_n\subset\Bbb{N}$ and $x_{n+k}$ is the least element of $X_n=X\setminus\{x_n,x_{n+1},...,x_{n+k-1}\}\subset\Bbb{N}$, then \begin{align}f(0)=x_n\quad and\quad f(n+k)=x_{n+k}\end{align} for all $n,k\in\Bbb{N}$. Thus, $f$ is surjective. Furthermore, if $f(j)=f(i)$ then $x_{n+j}=x_{n+i}$. Since $x_{n+i}$ is the least element of $X_{n+i}=X_n\setminus\{x_n,...,x_{n+i-1}\}$ and $x_{n+j}$ is the least element of $X_{n+j}$. We know by the well-ordering principle that the least element is unique. Suppose $X_{n+i}\neq X_{n+j}$ such that $X_{n+i}\subset X_{n+j}$ where $X_{n+j}=X_n\setminus\{x_n,...,x_{n+i},...,x_{n+j-1}\}$. Since $x_{n+i}\notin X_{n+j}$, then it cannot be the least element of $X_{n+j}$ and $x_{n+i}\neq x_{n+j}$, a contradiction. Therefore, it must be that $X_{n+i}=X_{n+j}$ which means $\vert X_{n+j}\vert =\vert X_{n+i}\vert$ and $i=j$. Hence, $f$ is also injective.

Comment: [Looks correct to me, but I'm unable to improve it and therefore abstain from an answer.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20097/how-to-answer-proof-verification-questions)

Comment: "by the well-ordering principle $X$ has a minimum element." That applies for **non-empty** $X$ and nowhere is mentioned that $X$ is non-empty. Same problem arises if $X$ is finite. Btw, what exactly is the definition of being countable? Is it not that  an injection $X\to\mathbb N$ must exist? If so then how about the inclusion?

Comment: You're assuming that $X$ is infinite. If you want an easier approach to show that $X\subseteq \Bbb N$ is at most countable you just need either an injection $X\to\Bbb N$ or a surjection $\Bbb N\to X$. Can you come up with one of those more easily?

Comment: @drhab: I just added that it's non-empty. What problem arises when $X$ is finite? By definition, a set is countable iff it has equal cardinality with $\Bbb{N}$ and I believe I've showed surjection and injection, did I made any mistakes on it?

Comment: @TheLastCipher I said: the same problem. If e.g. $X$ has one element then $X-\{x_0\}$ is empty. Acording to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set) a set is countable if it has the same cardinality of some subset of $\mathbb N$. So according to that definition there is nothing to prove. If $X$ is infinite then you can indeed define recursively $f(0)=\min X$ and $f(n+1)=\min X-\{f(0),\dots,f(n)\}$. In your question I read $f(0)=n$ but what is $n$ here? Also I miss a proper definition of $X_n$.

Comment: @ I am letting $n$ to be any natural number and I just added the definition of $X_n$. Lastly, I was using some book's definition of countable. Anyway, I think I understand all the corrections. Thank you!

Comment: This appears to be [a proof in search of a context](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22solution+in+search+of+a+problem%22).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro: you mean it's trivial?

Comment: It could be trivial, depending on what assumptions your're allowed to use and what logical precision you're working under, neither of which you provided as background to your problem. It's like asking someone for a computer program to compute the $n$-th prime number --- do you want it in machine language or in Fortran code or in Mathematica code?